# C: how to check for when coord[x][y] == coord[x][y]?

Tags: c, object, linked-list, coordinates

I am trying to make a maze game.

I have monsters that are 'M' and a treasure that is '*'.

If a monster 'M' eats the treasure '*', I want the game to print 'GAME OVER' and quit.

How do you check for if(monster[x][y] == treasure[x][y])?

Do I need to create a new method get_co_ord(struct game_object *object, unsigned x, unsigned y)?

Or is there a simpler way?

```
void monster_move() {
    list_node *monster = monster_position;
    list_node *treasure = treasure_position;
    game_object *obj;
    game_object *obj2;
    while (monster) {
        obj = monster->object;
        obj2 = treasure->object;

        monster = monster->next;
        if (obj->x == obj2->x && obj->y == obj2->y) {
            printf("THE TREASURE IS FOREVER LOST!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if(obj->x == obj2->x && obj->y == obj2->y) doesn't work obviously!

Comment: nested if()s work, but I get memory leaks! :(

Comment: I got it to work now, I forgot to free memory! hahaha

Answer (score 0):

Turns out you have to use nested ifs as && won't work!

```
if (obj->x == obj2->x) {
   if (obj->y == obj2->y) {
      printf("THE TREASURE IS FOREVER LOST!");
      free_mem();
      exit(0);
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you try if ((obj->x == obj2->x) && (obj->y == obj2->y)) and see if that works?

Comment: There is no reason why the `&&` shouldn't work, please don't assume that you have to use nested `if`s in this situation – the error is somewhere else, and you're just learning bad habits (like unnecessarily nesting the `if`s) if you assume that this is the reason… Is the code both in this answer and in the question copypasted directly from your program, without edits?

Comment: Have you allocated memory to list_nodes and game_objects?